# Digits validation using @Digits

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, model-view-controller

I'm using java @Digits annotation to validate digits. I wanted to validate a digit like **1.1.1**. Here is the code I used.

```
@NotBlank
    @DecimalMin(value = "0.0", inclusive = false)
    @Digits(integer=1, fraction=3, message = "unsupported number of digits for version.")
    private String messageVersion;
```

How can I do that?

Comment: And what doesn't work?

Comment: This code works to validate a digit like 1.1. It gives validation failure for 1.1.1 is there any way to implement access both of these values?

Comment: No as `1.1.1` isn't a valid number and both validations are for valid numbers.

Comment: Actually I need to validate a version number. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Write a validator yourself. The ones you are using now aren't going to help.